# PWA added to homescreen, AccountKit not redirecting

Tags: ios, homescreen, progressive-web-apps, account-kit

After adding our PWA to homescreen, when going to the login flow, on Android accountkit opens a tab in chrome, whilst on iOS, it opens inside the PWA, then the flow is broken as accountkit gets stuck on the verified page.

Does anyone knows how to force accountkit to open in a browser tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use the native iOS and Android SDKs for AccountKit, or if you prefer to continue using the web sdk, you must switch to the "Basic Web" SDK for AccountKit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webbasic

The Basic Web SDK does not use any Javascript, which is the root cause of the issue in iOS webviews. You can read more about it in the FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/faq/#faq_645353795617467

Comment: After reporting it as a bug, the Facebook AccountKit team recognized it as a limitation they have and suggested the same, using the basic web sdk. Thank you.